# Unknown NullPointerException in JavaFx append method

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, nullpointerexception

**Please don't tag this question as duplicate as it's a little more than just NullPointerEcxeption case.**

I'm struggling with one problem which i'm trying to understand and solve, even though application is working correctly but console gives an error message.

This is simple java chat and I'm learning socket programming. My app show an error every time I run my app or send a message, but messages I send are displayed properly:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at chat.client.ClientWindow.lambda$printMsg$0(**ClientWindow.java:88**)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch$$$capture(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

---

ClientWindow.java:88 - it's

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> textArea.appendText(msg + "\n"));
```

Here is my code, please help me understand what's wrong.

```
package chat.server;

import chat.network.TCPConnection;
import chat.network.TCPConnectionListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatServer extends Application implements TCPConnectionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ChatServer();
    }

    private final ArrayList<TCPConnection> connections = new ArrayList<>();

    private ChatServer(){
            System.out.println("Server running...");
            try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8189)) {
                while (true){
                    try {
                        new TCPConnection(this,serverSocket.accept());
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("TCPConnection exception: " + e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        connections.add(tcpConnection);
        sendToAllConnections("Client connected: " + tcpConnection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
        sendToAllConnections(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        connections.remove(tcpConnection);
        sendToAllConnections("Client disconnected: " + tcpConnection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("TCPConnection exception: " + e);
    }

    private void sendToAllConnections(String value){
            System.out.println(value);
        for (TCPConnection connection : connections)
            connection.sendString(value);
    }
}
```

```
package chat.client;

import chat.network.TCPConnection;
import chat.network.TCPConnectionListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ClientWindow extends Application implements TCPConnectionListener {

    private static final String IP_ADDRES = "192.168.1.190";
    private static final int PORT = 8189;
    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;
    @FXML
    private TextField writeArea;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameArea;
    @FXML
    private Button send;
    TCPConnection connection;

    public void buttonClickHandler(ActionEvent evt){
        String msg = writeArea.getText();
        if(msg.equals("") || msg.equals(null)) return;
        writeArea.setText(null);
        connection.sendString(nameArea.getText() + ": " + msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Java Chat");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 590, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               new ClientWindow();
            }
        });
    }


    public ClientWindow(){
        try {
            connection = new TCPConnection(this, IP_ADDRES, PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            printMsg("Connection Exception" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        printMsg("Connection ready...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
        printMsg(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        printMsg("Connection close...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
        printMsg("Connection Exception" + e);
    }

    private synchronized void printMsg(String msg){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> textArea.appendText(msg + "\n"));
    }

}
```

```
package chat.network;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TCPConnection {

    private final Socket socket;
    private final Thread rxThread;
    private final TCPConnectionListener eventListener;
    private final BufferedReader in;
    private final BufferedWriter out;

    public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, String idAddr, int port) throws IOException {
        this(eventListener, new Socket(idAddr,port));
    }

    public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
        this.socket = socket;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        rxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    eventListener.onConnectionReady(TCPConnection.this);
                    while(!rxThread.isInterrupted()) {
                        eventListener.onReceiveString(TCPConnection.this,in.readLine());
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
                }finally {
                    eventListener.onDisconnect(TCPConnection.this);
                }
            }
        });
        rxThread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void sendString(String value){
        try {
            out.write(value + "\r\n");
            out.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void disconnect(){
        rxThread.interrupt();
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TCPConnection: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ": " + socket.getPort();
    }
}
```

```
package chat.network;

public interface TCPConnectionListener {

    void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection);
    void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value);
    void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection);
    void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e);
}
```

P.S. I tried to make Java Swing GUI instead JavaFX it works.
Also, I didn't include fxml file with all elements.

Comment: If this is a pure JavaFX application, you need to use `Platform.runlater()` not `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Just a guess.

Comment: @Sedrick thx for good advice I'll keep it in mind next time, but it didn't help in my case :(

Comment: Well, you use `SwingUtilities` at least twice. The other big problem is that you have extended application on both your controller classes. JavaFX was not designed to be used in this manner(another guess). This structure lends itself to problems.

Comment: @Sedrick yeah I know :( that was just attempt to know how app will behave. Even though I delete all extra code it doesn’t change anything :(

Comment: I have done over 50 tutorials on JavaFX from a bunch of different sites. Not once have I seen a tutorial where a controller extends application.  Yet, I have seen a few questions were people are doing this. So I am curious. Where did you learn this practice?

Comment: @Sedrick Nowhere I’m beginner and have no knowledge, I’m just learning from different sources , and trying something new and then observe result. This app is definitely rubbish , but here I’m trying to understand how it works and why it doesn’t work properly

Comment: I suggest you start with complete tutorials. Very simple stuff first in both pure code and FXML flavors. Then move up to more complicated stuff. Once you have a really good understanding of the basics, then create your own stuff based on things you find interesting (like your app above^).

Comment: @Sedrick thx for advice :)